# File system based B+ Tree implementation in c#

Tags: c#, b-tree

Is there any file system based B+ Tree implementation in c#(open source). I have found some projects, but those are not file(disk) based implementation. I am specifically looking for file system based B+ Trees.

Comment: What... is it too localized..? come on guys

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211204/c-sharp-custom-database-engine-how-to-implement-sql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:**

I've added some [benchmarks of managed B-Tree implementations](http://csharptest.net/?p=586) for your enjoyment if you looking into this sort of thing.

> BplusDotNet "... is known to be somewhat buggy on deletes"

I found just the opposite to be true, RaptorDB 1.6 was corrupting state and BplusDotNet 1.0.2082.16942 seemed to work well enough.

**Original:**

For completeness I'm going to add my own implementation here.

- Introduction - http://csharptest.net/?page_id=563
- Benchmarks  - http://csharptest.net/?p=586
- Online Help - [http://help.csharptest.net/](http://help.csharptest.net/?CSharpTest.Net.BPlusTree~CSharpTest.Net.Collections.BPlusTree%602_members.html)
- Source Code - http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/
- Downloads - http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/downloads
- NuGet Package - http://nuget.org/List/Packages/CSharpTest.Net.BPlusTree

Comment: I can confirm that BPlusTree DOES corrupt data when reading via a custom ISerializer<T> serializer. Entities has inbuilt SHA256 based HMACs for self-checks and would failed 1:50K times (IO streams would be closed out prematurely). Also performance drops, so reading the last 10% entities is MUCH slower than reading the first 10%. Problems went away when perform same serialization of T => byte[] outside BPlusTree and BPlusTree uses PrimitiveSerializer.Bytes to work with just byte[] instead of a custom entity. Project likely dead since NuGet has seen no release in 1.5 years

Comment: @DeepSpace101 can you share your implementation of the ISerializer?  I suspect your issue is possibly there.  The BPlusTree is currently in use in several commercial offerings and has proven reliable as you indicate you experienced by using the byte[] and built-in serializer.  As to the project being dead, I can certainly understand the impression as I've not made any significant improvements to it in a long time.  I'm happy to help you and others with it, just shoot me an email roger @ my username.

Comment: Will email you but the root cause was that the serializer had a convention that end-of-stream = end of object. That convention/assumption was broken at the `T ReadFrom(Stream stream)` interface, resulting in more bytes (beyond the 'end') to be read, killing the crypto-checksums.

Comment: @DeepSpace101 I suspected as much, I've been bitten by the same.  At least it's documented here for the next person ;)

Comment: Also, it would happen just 1:50K times (vs every time) because the `ReadFrom` would happen only if the disk was hit for the read. Since we were writing => reading (back to back), reads happened off a cache. But if the disk was hit even once (1:50K times at app level), we saw that error. Our fix was to handle serialization outside the BPlusTree library and just use the byte[] interface into BPlusTree.

Answer (score 2):

http://bplusdotnet.sourceforge.net/ but this one is known to be somewhat buggy on deletes.

Another one that appears to work well:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/RaptorDB.aspx

RaptorDB allows you to store key/values either indexed using a b+ tree or a hash index. You can pick when you create the files.